# how to duplicate a complex object along path in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Beginner in inkscape, I would like to make something that feel simple : I want to make a picture with cat's paw print along a path, as if a cat had walked in the snow.

For this I :

- found a svg image of a cat's paw print
- duplicate it and put it in front on the first
- group the whole, and convert to path
- draw a line along which I would like my paw print to be arranged

Then I tried two thing :

- extensions/generate from path /pattern along path : inkscape put my line along the paw print and not the reverse...
- path/path effect/pattern along path : I have a single paw print

It's frustrating because I followed a lots of tuto, and all work well with simple shape I make directly in inkscape (star, circle...) but with my paw print, I can't make it work. I probably miss something really stupid, can someone spot it ?

Comment: I recommend migrating this question to [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this one out and looked over the 'Help' option on the function, which states:

"There must be a single pattern object must be the topmost [in the Layers & Objects tab] for the pattern, groups of paths, groups of shapes or clone are allowed. Text Must be converted to path before using as a pattern."

Arranging the paths as suggested produced perfect results.